# python regex re.compile and re.search

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

real_comp = re.compile(r'[0-9]*')
real_comp.search('+123i').group()
Out[7]: ''
```

I am expecting the the result as "123", but it returns empty. 
What's wrong?

Comment: You are searching for a substring of *zero or more* digits.  Your string `+123i` does indeed contain such a substring, of zero length, at the very start.  You probably want `+` (one or more) instead of `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another quantifier, namely a `+`:

```
import re

real_comp = re.compile(r'([0-9]+)')
print(real_comp.search('+123i').group())
```

Which yields

```
123
```

Otherwise the regex engine reports a match before the very first consumed char ( `[0-9]*` is always true).